# Hide gamemode change announcements

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-spigot

I have a Minecraft Server (1.12.2) running Vanilla minecraft with some special features programmed into command blocks.

There are areas where players go from Survival Mode into Adventure, etc. I find the gamemode change announcements to be annoying and sort of immersion-breaking to the gameplay. How can I hide these from no-OP players (or all players)?

I already have `/gamerule sendCommandFeedback false` which is great, but it doesn't prevent the game from telling individual players "Your game mode has been updated to Adventure Mode" or "Your game mode has been updated to Survival Mode".

Is there any way in vanilla to stop these individual notifications from appearing?  If not, what about a spigot plugin? I'm not opposed to using spigot instead of straight vanilla. I looked through tons of plugins and did several searches, but I'm coming up empty handed.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a server resource pack that the clients will by default automatically download. In it, you can have a lot of language files, one for each language, all the same, containing only the line to replace the gamemode update message with nothing (or a space, whatever works).

With this, players will see an empty line in chat. So if you also have other things in chat, they will still get shifted up.

Using this method, the message is by default deactivated for everyone, but players who know what's going on can enable it if they want to.

Comment: Wow, this is actually very clever

Answer (score 1):

type /gamerule logAdminCommands false, this should do the trick so when you type commands in it shouldn't display it to the player in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off the game rule `logAdminCommands`.

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to hide commandblock output from all players, you can change the gamerule with the following command:

```
/gamerule commandblockoutput false
```

Comment: That doesn't address the question that was asked.

Answer (score -4):

Well.. Just get the player.advancement.gamemodeChange.*  as I recall, and use a mod or plugin to disable it. I'm sure it's there somewhere.

Comment: This is not very clear and not very helpful.